# PHP imagefilter parameter IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH value ranges question?

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

what is the value range I can use for the imagefilter function parameter IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH?

Comment: please expand your question to contain more detail.

Comment: what is the min and max values can I have for the IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like there's no real limit to the range, at least not in any documentation I've seen.  However, there is a short explanation of the value [here](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/11/2/15):

> There isn't enough room here to go
>   into a full discussion of what these
>   manipulation matrices are, but suffice
>   to say you can represent many
>   different transformations - from
>   Gaussian blur to edge detection -
>   using a 3x3 numerical matrix that
>   defines how the colours of the eight
>   pixels surrounding any given pixel
>   (with the pixel itself being the
>   ninth) should have their RGB values
>   changed. With IMG_FILTER_SMOOTH, the
>   parameter you pass is used as the
>   change value for the pixel itself,
>   which means you get to define how much
>   the pixel's own colour is used to form
>   its final color.
>
> You're not likely to want values
>   outside of the range -8 to 8, as even
>   one number makes quite a big
>   difference. At about 10 the picture is
>   almost normal because the original
>   pixel values are given more weight
>   than the combined sum of its
>   neighbours, but you can get some
>   really neat effects between -6 to -8 -
>   do play around and see what you can
>   come up with.